# How would I move SQL MSSQL.1 and MSSQL.2 location?

Tags: sql-server, installation, datafile

We have a SQL instance where the MSSQL.1 and MSSQL.2 were installed on a SAN drive. We are moving away from this SAN do to faults and we wish to move the files and folders to a new SAN. How would we do this?

All DB datafiles have been moved and are up and running again, I just want to know if it is necessary to move these over:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Before you do anything else: http://www.bobpusateri.com/archive/2013/03/moving-a-database-to-new-storage-with-no-downtime/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First shut down sql server

Then the best option is to robocopy everything from the disk to the new disk with the existing security.

when this is done, remove the old disk, and give the drive letter of that disk to the disk which you robocopied to. After that start SQL Server again.

This way SQL Server will not notice they are now on a new disk.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this during our maintenance window this weekend.

Comment: "I just want to know if it is necessary to move these over", says the OP. Is your answer supposed to mean "yes"?

Comment: Depending on whether the installation files and system databases are present in those folders, but as I can see it will be the system database, I personally prefer this way to move. So yes it is necessary if the system databases and installation files are present in those folder, NO if they are not But in this case I think it will be a Yes

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL Server database files changed to a new SAN. Shutdown the old SQL Server and robocopy or xcopy the Old files to the new Disk. (Besure that you use the same drive letter as on the Old Disk) Besure you also copied the security of the old disk to the new disk.

xcopy "C:\Source Folder" "C:\Destination folder" /X /H /E
/X – Copies file audit settings and file ownership and ACL information.
/H – Copies hidden and system files.
/E – Copies directories and subdirectories, including empty ones.

robocopy H:\Microsoft SQL Server H:\Microsoft SQL Server /E /SEC
Be aware that you use the same drive letter on the new SAN. 
You can also rename the old disk and rename the new disk to h:\
now you can copy the OlDDIKS:\Microsoft SQL Server to H:\Microsoft SQL Server